# I am getting an error on @ionic-native/contacts

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I installed this package
@ionic-native/contacts
[enter image description here][1]
Facing an error visible in attachment.

My Cordova version:- 11
Ionic:- 4
Angular :- 8

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3J79.png![error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3J79.png!%5Berror) screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDoi6.png)

Comment: Is this stopping you from running, building and deploying the app? That plugin is just deprecated and will continue working... for a while... probably. You might consider moving to Capacitor and newer plugins.

Comment: I run :- ionic cordova run android , then app installed on my real device, i checked console on browser, its giving me an error,   can't find property find

Comment: Are other plugin methods working? Can you trigger contact picker with `pickContact`? Also, which version of the plugin are you using?

Comment: I am using :- "@ionic-native/contacts": "^5.36.0"

and  getting bellow error by using pickContact function

navigator.contacts.pickContact is not a function
TypeError: navigator.contacts.pickContact is not a function

Comment: Can you add alerts at important points in the code and build the app to test it on device? It might behave differently on browser+device run, and it might also be due to opening contacts client sending your app to background.

Comment: I got the solution. I used capacitor instead of Cordova.  
I run 
ionic capacitor run android --device

thanks for the support. :)

Comment: Question should be formated so other user can easily understand. specially picture should be formated.